# Setting option to selected for drop down from an array.

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Im using Classic ASP, I have an array that i loop though to fill the drop down box. Im trying to make it so when you submit the form it keeps the value that is selected.

```
<select name="ID" style="border-width: 1px; width: 260px;" >
                <%
                    For idx = 1 to Ubound (g_Array)
                    %>
                        <option value="<%response.Write(idx)%>"
                        <% If Request.Form("ID") = idx Then Response.Write("selected") %>> <%response.write(g_Array(idx))%>
                        </option>
                    <%
                    next
                %>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `cint`. Querystring and form variables are treated as strings by default, you need to tell ASP to treat them as integers.

```
<select name="ID" style="border-width: 1px; width: 260px;" >


<%
                For idx = 1 to Ubound (g_Array)
                %>
                    <option value="<%=idx%>"
                    <% If cint(Request.Form("ID")) = idx Then Response.Write("selected") %>> <%=g_Array(idx)%>
                    </option>
                <%
                next
            %>
        </select>
```

Note that you can use `<%=idx%>` as a shorter alternative to `<%response.Write(idx)%>`